# TypeError: only size-1 arrays error in Newton-Raphson Algorithm

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on Scientific calculation in Python and using Newton-Raphson Algorithm but face an issue and unfortunately couldn't solve.

I am running that code in Spyder(Python3.6) and my machine is Windows 10.

```
N=361

t3 = mt.pi/4   #Initial Guess for Newton-Raphson
t4 = mt.pi/2   #Initial Guess for Newton-Raphson

for i in range(1,N):

    theta2[i-1] = (i-1)*(2*mt.pi)/(N-1)

    #Newton-Raphson Calculation
    for j in range(1,6):
        phi11 = a*mt.cos((i-1)*(2*mt.pi)/(N-1)) + b*mt.cos(t3) - c*mt.cos(t4) - d
        phi12 = a*mt.sin((i-1)*(2*mt.pi)/(N-1)) + b*mt.sin(t3) - c*mt.sin(t4)

        phi = np.array([[phi11], [phi12]])
```

After that calculation, I am re-defining theta2 array by for loop.

Comment: I love it, a guessing game!  Guess where the error occurs and what variable is involved.  But for a start, what is `mt`?

Comment: Sorry for nor adding that detail. I imported two Python modules as import numpy as np and import math as mt. The mt is math module

Comment: `math` functions only accept scalars or single item arrays.  `np.sin` works with arrays.

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem